# Multipurpose buttons

Tags: unity, c#, input, control, statemachine

As in the title, I am trying to figure out how to use a button for multiple purposes in Unity.

In my specific case for instance, I am currently using the joystick button 0 (the A button) to perform a simple melee attack:

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && currentState != PlayerState.attack && currentState != PlayerState.stagger) 
//second clause because I do not want to indefinitely attack every frame
{
    StartCoroutine(GetComponent<Player_Melee>().FirstAttack());                    
}
```

In the conditions I make sure that I am pressing the right button and determining in which state my player is (the state is then changed in the attack coroutine).
In order to interact with a given object, I created a trigger to check that the player is within range to inspect the object:

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Interact_Alt") && playerInRange)
{
    if (dialogueBox.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        dialogueBox.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        dialogueBox.SetActive(true);
        dialText.text = dialogue;
    }
}
```

In the Input manager settings in unity, I set the 'Interact_Alt' button to be the same as the 'Fire1' used in the attack script. The scripts actually work, however whenever I check an object I also perform an attack. How can i make so that when I want to inspect an object I do not attack?

I was considering create a new finite state similarly to the one I use to attack e.g. 'PlayerState.interact', but then I was wondering, how would unity give the priority to which command to use?

Another alternative would be to check if I am in the range of some object when I want to attack and if within range it inspects the object instead, but it seems to me a much more convoluted solutions.

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. For information, the solution i used was to create a boolean attached to the player that upon entering in the trigger area of the object in question would have been turned true and prevent to use the button to perform an attack, allowing instead to only inspect the object.